# Div overflow on large svg

Tags: svg, d3.js, overflow

I display large svg representing charts and created using d3js inside div element with overflow set to auto, so that I can scroll the chart content.
I have a strange behavior that I cannot explain, so I would like some help or hints on what could be the reason of that weird result I have.
It happens with pixel width svg of over 11 million px.  So when I have svg of that width and over, starting at the same position on the page, the svg element is displayed in the opposite direction, from left to right.
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: The short answer is that your browser is not designed to support web pages (or components of web pages) that are millions of pixels wide.  You're maxing out the limit of numerical data types used in the source code, and in computers when you increase a number passed the limit, you end up with a negative number.  So everything is displayed flipped.

Comment: Allright, that is bad, but thank you for this explanation.  Is there any way to solve that ?  My solution is based on this exemple http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/2014/05/17/d3-scalability-virtual-scrolling-for-large-visualizations/, adapted for my purpose to scroll a line chart.

Comment: If you're only drawing the visible elements, then you don't need all that extra SVG pixel width space; it's just there so the default DOM scrollbar shows up and works as expected.  Instead, you can implement your own scroll bar; look up examples of the d3 drag behaviour and pan/zoom behaviour to get an idea of where to start.